# What happened to Annu Kapoor's role in Anupamaa?

Tags: casting, anupamaa

For the show *Anupamaa* there was a promo with Annu Kapoor and it was advertised everywhere and got covered in news:

But he didn't appear on the show till now and when Anupamaa joined the job there was a female principal.

What happened to Annu's role?